TV-movie or mini series 1985-1990 - Boy dream of being a pilot
This movie is extremely unknown. I've searched for ages and asked dozens of people about this, and still nothing. It doesn't help that I watched this movie almost 30 years ago when I was 8-10 years old.
I'm pretty sure the lenght of the movie was over 3 hours, which leads me to believe it was a tv-movie or mini-series.
The movie is about a mentally challenged boy/guy (I think late teens early twenties) who still lives with his mother. His father, who died before or in the beginning of the movie, was a helicopter pilot. The boy always dreamed of becoming a helicopter pilot, just like his dad. But, of course, due to him being mentally handicapped, this was never going to happen.
His mother was involved in exposing something that would extend to her becoming a target. I have no idea anymore if this had something to do with the father.
The end (total spoiler): The mother is speaker in an outdoor conference with full media-exposure and revealing the things she found out. A bullet is on her way, but the boy jumps in front of the bullet and saves her. He then opens his eyes and finds himself taking off in a helicopter, his dream come true.
Hope someone can help me with this one!

What country was it likely from or what language was it in?

Some of this sounds like The World According to Garp, the 1982 movie starring Robin Williams. He "flew" as a baby. He had a dysfunctional relationship with his single mother. At the end he is shot, gets airlifted to the hospital in a helicopter, and says something happily about flying (even though he's dying). However, many of the other details do not match. Is it possible you are combining 2 movies in your memory?

@Paulie_D It was definitely a US movie. Thanks, Brett! May well be that I combined 2 movies in my memory, as I was probably only 8 years old when I watched it. I'll watch the movie tonight, and hopefully find that this is the one I was searching for.
